# Advantages and disadvantages of mixing Http and websockets when building a chat app?

Tags: design-patterns, websocket, xmlhttprequest, real-time

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217209/is-it-ok-to-use-http-rest-api-for-chat-application), but it asks if it is okay to use http only and avoid websockets completely when building a chat app.

My situation is:

I have a simple chat app I am building. When sending a new message I am using an Http Post request(I am using Angular) to send the data to the server where it is persisted in the database, then is broadcasted via sockets to the appropriate clients. Are there any advantage or disadvantages of doing it like this? Instead of just using web sockets throughout?

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58654499/is-there-any-need-advantage-of-calling-an-api-using-the-http-client-service-when) you should avoid using sockets where possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it either way, but since you want to make a *simple* chat app, then you should probably use HTTP to send messages and a web socket to receive channel updates.

On both the client and server side, this will avoid complexities involved in multiplexing both inbound and outbound events over the same connection.  This often turns out to be non-trivial, especially if you have to fall back from web sockets to long polling.

Comment: Thanks, but I am still wondering what the drawbacks are of choosing one over the other? I am trying to know them so my decision can be as informed as possible. My exact scenario is that I am using the socket.io library. And will the Http be slower than sockets.io? What if I plan to add more features to the chat app will http still be a good choice for sending the messages?